# Missing Script: webpack in npm

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I'm trying to re-build a react app and bundle it using webpack. Whenever I try to run `npm run-script build` it would always show a  `npm ERR! missing script: webpack`

Things that I've tried:

1. Deleted the node_modules folder the doing a `npm install` (again)
2. installed the webpack globally
3. installed the webpack-cli

You may notice that I am using old version of some modules. This is because this is a legacy app built before I was employed and now I am trying to integrate the app that I built into this app but before that I would like to understand how the whole thing works as vanilla.

Below is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "storyline-feedback-tool",
  "version": "1.1.2",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start-hot": "node server.js",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --content-base public/ --inline --port 3001"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.13.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "g": "^2.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.15.0",
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
    "react-spin": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^1.15.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.24.0",
    "eslint": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.1.2",
    "less": "^2.7.1",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.11.0",
    "postcss-pxtorem": "^3.3.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.15.1"
  }
}
```

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var postcssPxtorem = require('postcss-pxtorem');


var config = {
  name: 'feedback-tool',
  entry: {
    'feedback-main': './src/index-main.js',
    'feedback-form': './src/index-form.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/feedback'),
    publicPath: '/feedback/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  }
};

config.module = {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      loader: 'babel',
    },
    {
      test: /\.less$/,
      loader: "style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!less-loader"
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: "style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader"
    }
  ]
};

config.postcss = function () {
  return [
    autoprefixer({
      browsers: [
        'last 2 version',
        'ie > 8']
    }),
    postcssPxtorem({
      propWhiteList: []
    })]
};

config.plugins = [
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
   compress: {
   warnings: false,
   },
   output: {
   comments: false,
   },
  }),
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
   'process.env': {
   'NODE_ENV': '"production"'
   }
  }),
];

module.exports = config;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is webpack correctly installed globally, `webpack -v works? Is webpack installed locally, `npx webpack -v` works? I don't think it makes any difference, but I usually run it using `npm run build` :)

Comment: Yes, it shows me the version number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message of: `npm ERR! missing script: webpack` makes me believe your **webpack installation screwed up** somewhere down the line or having webpack **installed globally is causing issues** due to the legacy nature of this project. Could you try the following and see if this resolves your issue:

1. Ensure that your **version of node is compatible with webpack.** The documentation recommends using the LTS version of [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/): **10.15.1 LTS**. Directly from webpack's [documentation:](https://webpack.js.org/guides/installation/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx)

   "Before we begin, make sure you have a fresh version of Node.js installed. The current Long Term Support (LTS) release is an ideal starting point. You may run into a **variety of issues with the older versions as they may be missing functionality webpack and/or its related packages require.**"
2. **Uninstall Webpack and the CLI**:

   `npm uninstall -g webpack
   npm uninstall webpack-cli`
3. **Re-Install webpack and the cli locally** since installing webpack globally may cause issues:

   "Note that this is **not a recommended practice**. Installing globally locks you down to a **specific version of webpack and could fail in projects that use a different version**."

   `npm install --save-dev webpack
    npm install --save-dev webpack-cli`
4. Update your **custom build command** to **include the path to your webpack.config.js file**.

   `"scripts": {
       "build": "webpack --config <path_to_webpack_config>/webpack.config.js",
       "start-hot": "node server.js",
       "start": "webpack-dev-server --content-base public/ --inline --port 3001"
   },`
5. Try running your build script again:

   `npm run build`

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Hello Nathan, I followed your instructions and got it working. I agree that step 3 might cause issues, especially during integration. I'm thinking of making a newer version for this legacy project that uses the current react then integrate it to the app by then. Thanks!

Comment: np glad it help

Answer (score 11):

in my case I just add to node "Scripts" the key "webpack":"webpack". and that worked for me.

`{
  "name": "reactdemo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "lmora demo",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },`

Comment: This fixed it for me! Thanks!

Comment: This is correct.That fixed my problem.Thanks.